# JQtouch screen resolution for android

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jqtouch, screen-size

Hi i am trying out JQtouch Tutorial, however when i run the sample onto my android device, 
it does not fit my screen totally, it's like there is a white colour border surrounding the JQtouch layout and the title of myApp.

I believe it is not a problem with the support-screens attribute inside the manifest file, but is something to do with jqtouch.

Anyone knows how can i possibly correct the white border surrounding my JQtouch interface?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer this without the code, however it sounds like you are experiencing some sort of margin in the css. But like I said its hard to help on this without seeing it. I would recommend using Chrome's inspect element and looking through the CSS elements and looking for a margin